# Spring Data Neo4j 4 - No Identity Field Found For Class

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I am trying to create new Project and make simple class, Master and Pet class.

This is my Master Class

```
package com.david.duck.model;

import java.util.Set;

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.*;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@NodeEntity
public class Master {

    @GraphId
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @Relationship(type="OWNS")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Pet> pets;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Pet> getPets() {
        return pets;
    }

    public void setPets(Set<Pet> pets) {
        this.pets = pets;
    }
    public Master(){
        super();
    }
}
```

and this is my Pet class

```
package com.david.duck.model;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GraphId;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship;

@NodeEntity
public class Pet {
    @GraphId
    Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @Relationship(type="OWNS")
    private Master master;

    public Master getMaster() {
        return master;
    }

    public void setMaster(Master master) {
        this.master = master;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Pet(){
        super();
    }
}
```

At Controller, I am trying to create new Master and save it, and then create Pet that the master is the one that I created before.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.MappingException: No identity field found for class: com.david.duck.model.Master
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:981) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585) [jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577) [jetty-security-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) [jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544) [jetty-io-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) [jetty-util-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) [jetty-util-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_65]
Caused by: org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.MappingException: No identity field found for class: com.david.duck.model.Master
    at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.info.ClassInfo.identityField(ClassInfo.java:310) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.entityaccess.DefaultEntityAccessStrategy.getIdentityPropertyReader(DefaultEntityAccessStrategy.java:476) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.getNodeBuilder(EntityGraphMapper.java:202) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntity(EntityGraphMapper.java:154) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.map(EntityGraphMapper.java:91) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.save(SaveDelegate.java:67) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.save(SaveDelegate.java:43) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.save(Neo4jSession.java:386) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepositoryImpl.save(GraphRepositoryImpl.java:46) ~[spring-data-neo4j-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:468) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.david.duck.controller.UserController.getMaster(UserController.java:70) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.david.duck.controller.UserController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f84cec8b.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.david.duck.controller.UserController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$68608fde.getMaster(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `@GraphId` field cannot be a primitive long. It should be

`@GraphId Long id;`

in `Master`

Comment: Oh my, i am not focus. It was my bad. Thank you very much.